# removing a specific character from a string

Tags: crystal-reports

I do not have very much knowledge of programming and really need help. I am pulling reports from a field contains a string of text that is limited to 80 characters. If someone enters more than 80 characters, a "+" is added and the text continues. So I want to remove all the "+" signs or every 81st character. I have tried using Replace formulas but have not been able to make it work. field name is rlmain.desc. Need help with the formula and where to place it. Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
Replace({rimain.desc},"+","")
```

Comment: I didn't have the brackets in my formula